# How to apply an upgrade python package whithout stop Django server?

Tags: python, django, pip

I have a Django Server that uses a X package, these package i upgrade daily. I don’t want to Stop my Django instance every day when the package was updated.
I have a Cron daily to Upgrade the Package (Pip package -U), 
but the Django doesn’t use the latest version upgrated. Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to update the package daily? Usually you would need to make sure, that the update does not break anything with your code.

Comment: because it's a package that need to upgrade... because it's changes..

Comment: Why exactly do you want to avoid reloading the server?

Comment: Because the server is always working...

Comment: You could try to use @pozcircuitboys answer below. I still do not understand why you think it's necessary to immediately update a python package. As long as there are no fixes for security vulnerabilities, it is not necessary.

How many concurrent users do you have that a short downtime would be a problem? If that is indeed the case, you should probably think about changing your deploy strategy to some kind of zero-downtime deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Generally doing a software update to a running service implies some kind of a restart or reload of that service. In many cases, if you force this, it may work for some amount of time but may cause difficult to find bugs; java is infamous for working until the next occasional subroutine (ie, log collection) happens if you upgrade the jdk version in-place like this.

I'm not sure what kind of modules you're modifying here, but in some cases you might try out https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions to see if the manage.py shell_plus autoreload may serve your needs.